# External drive not appearing for downloads

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

My old 360 60gb hard drive, plugged into new Xbox (by transfer cable) will not show up when I want to download something (Halo 4 online maps, for example) but will show up when I transfer things.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an HDD Drive from an older system as a save location for a Slim Xbox. On the [Microsoft website for the transfer cable](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/set-up-transfer-cable):

> Use only the Xbox 360 Transfer Cable to move your content.

Corroborated [here](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/7/p/21274/133374.aspx#133374).

Note that there is a way to get this to work, but it isn't officially supported by Microsoft. [This answer on Yahoo!](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120418155913AAvc4Fz) could be a starting point, and also confirms that you can't use the transfer cable and an old hard drive as a save location.